# Como incluir ou remover enter, quebra de linha, nova linha de uma string - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, quebras-de-linha

Como remover ou incluir a "quebra de linha", "enter", "nova linha" de um resultado de string no postgres.

O resultado é:

```
comentário
Texto do comentário
Mais texto
```

E eu quero:

```
comentário
Texto do comentário - Mais texto
```

Ou ao contrário

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover, podemos usar:

```
select regexp_replace(sua_coluna, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' - ', 'g' )
```

OU

```
select regexp_replace(sua_coluna, '[\n\r]+', ' - ', 'g' )
```

Para inclui uma nova linha use:

```
select E'Primeira Linha\nSegunda linha.'
```

OU

```
select E'Primeira Linha'||chr(10)||'Segunda linha.'
```

OU conforme o @David

```
select E'Primeira Linha'||chr(13)||'Segunda linha.'
```

Fontes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836906/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-and-new-lines-in-postgresql

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638615/insert-line-break-in-postgresql-when-updating-text-field

Para mais informações, leia o manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Além do Chr(10) = Retorno de Carro = Carriage Return, temos o Chr(13) = Avanço de linha = Line Feed. :)

Comment: Obrigado @David, editei a resposta